# wont decrement the value given

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to get the results as shown in the question attached in the photo [image]

how ever the results I am getting are the exact opposite of what I want

[image]

please help me identify the problem

Here is the correction after @scott's reply

```
(defun decrementing (num)
         (if( = 1 num) 
                 (princ "the number has reach 1. goodbye.")
             (if ( = (- num 1) 10)
             (format t "~&") 
           (format t "the next number is ~d. ~&" (- num 1)
              ))) (decrementing (- num 1)))
```

I got the solution but the loop never ends

Comment: Why would `(= (- num 1) 10)` ever be true?

Comment: Is there are reason you paste text as a picture?

Comment: @ScottHunter hmmm good question

Comment: @ScottHunter I edited the code above, but now I can't manage to get the loop to end.

Answer (score 1):

You put the recursive part of your function *inside* the call to `format`, so that it doesn't actually print until *after* the recursion has finished (because all of the arguments to `format` have to be evaluated before `format` itself can do its printing).

Comment: Do you mean like this ? 

'code'

(defun decrementing (num)
             (if( = 1 num) 
                     (princ "the number has reach 1. goodbye.")
                 (if ( = (- num 1) 10)
                 (format t "~&") 
                   (decrementing (- num 1)
               (format t "the next number is ~d. ~&" (- num 1)
                   )))))

'code'


now it only prints the 9th line

Comment: I that case, I only get the 9th line, nothing else gets printed

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun decrementing (num)
         (if( = 1 num) 
                 (princ "the number has reach 1. goodbye.")
             (if ( = (- num 1) 0)
             (format t "~&") 
           (format t "the next number is ~d. ~&" (- num 1)
              ))) (if (> num 1)(decrementing (- num 1))))
```

I have managed to solve the problem, thank you sooo much for the help